# Kill inferior python in python.el mode

Tags: python, process

At the moment I am killing the Python interpreter with `C-d` each time I want to quit Python interpreter.

What is the name of the function to kill the Python interpreter in Python mode (the one which comes with Emacs) so that I can bind it to a key command?

Comment: Welcome to Emacs Stack Exchange! If I've answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it and it will give you +2 to your rep! Cheers!

Comment: If nothing works for you, you can kill the python interpreter by simply typing inside the command ```quit()```.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want `comint-stop-subjob` but it looks like it's already bound to `C-c C-z` for you.

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Mode.html):

> `C-c C-z`
>
> > Stop the shell or its current subjob if any (`comint-stop-subjob`). This command also kills any shell input pending in the shell buffer
> >     and not yet sent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! `C-c C-z` doesn't kill the python shell, but simply changes to the buffer having the shell in it. The right command for me was `C-c C-\\`, thanks for the link enyway.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the command you're looking for is `(comint-send-eof)`.

You can bind it with something like:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'comint-send-eof)
```

It is bound, by default, to `C-c C-d`.